# Put indeterminate ProgressBar inside of PreferenceFragment's ListPreference

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How could I put a 'spinning' progress bar inside of a listpreference layout? It starts with an empty content (in fact there should only be the progressbar) and once the list content is processed the spinbar should be replaced by my content.

How can I implement this through XML?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry it's too long, but did you get it done ?

Answer (score 0):

I like this approximation

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:lib="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/mylist"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />

   <ProgressBar 
       android:id="@+id/mypb"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in your activity, just set the progressBar with visibility GONE when your listview fullfill with data

```
//data arrives in list
List<ListViewData> data = getData();
ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mypb);
mListViewAdapter.addAll(data);
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE)
mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: And what do I need to put into my xml/preferences.xml?

Comment: The xml above could represent your preferences screen, "layout/preferences_activity.xml" for example. I dont understand why do you need nothing more in xml/preferences.xml. Can you give more info about what you need to do?

Comment: I am working inside a PreferenceFragment. The UI is built upon my xml/preferences.xml which contains my PreferenceScreen. In my class I use addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences) in order to get my settings switches handled.